# Do Arcane Tricksters need a spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment

In order to store their arcane spells, does an Arcane Trickster rogue need a spellbook?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. A spellbook is a wizard-specific class feature (Player's Handbook p.114) and is not required for other classes unless specified.

The Arcane Trickster has a limited number of Spells Known, like a sorcerer (even though they cast from the wizard spell list). This differs from the wizard, who has no "Spells Known" limit but stores his spells in a spellbook.

Comment: So where do they get their spells from? How do they end up with magical skills? Takes a wizard years of learning but the arcane trickster just pulls them out his/her butt? :D